# Back-substitution

Tags: replacement, expression-manipulation

Suppose that we have an expression (expr in the code below) and replace a long term with a new parameter (K).

For a simple example;

```
expr = (5 I (Subscript[a, 1] - Sqrt[
     Subscript[a, 1] (6 + Subscript[a, 1])]) x)/(3 y \[Alpha]);
newVariables = {(Subscript[a, 1] - Sqrt[
      Subscript[a, 1] (6 + Subscript[a, 1])]) -> K};
expr //. newVariables
```

After some calculations, we derive a new expression (expr2 in the code below). What is the best and most reliable method for automatically back-substituion K to expr2? (instead of manually applying `expr2//.K->(Subscript[a, 1] - Sqrt[Subscript[a, 1] (6 + Subscript[a, 1])])` )

```
expr2 = K^2 + 5 I K x
```

Comment: Is this what you want: ``expr2 /. Reverse /@ newVariables``?

Comment: Yes. Thank you.